# Cell formatting for Millions of dollars

Tags: excel

I'm working with large numbers here, so I want to save space in each cell by displaying

```
$1,782,543 as $1.78M
```

I'm formatting the cell using the following custom formatter:

```
$#.0,," M";
```

It seems to be working, except when the number is negative.  Then it displays nothing.  Any idea what could be causing this?

Perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes **after** the `semi-colon`is the format applied to negative values, as you have nothing after the `semi-colon` negative values are blank......so just leave out the `semi-colon` and the same format is applied to all values, positive negative or zero (but with "-" sign for negative numbers), i.e. use just

`$#.0,," M"`

Comment: that seemed to work great. any idea on how to format the cell to show nothing if the value is 0? $.0M just doesn't look great

Comment: This version will do that - `[<>0]$#.0,," M";`

Answer (score 2):

The format for a custom number format is *<positive number>;<negative number>;<zero>;<text>*.

If you add some format masks for the other possible number variations you should be fine. Example:

`$#.0,," M"_);[Red]($#.0,," M");[color14]_(* "-"??_);[color5]_(@_)`

[image: Custom Number Format]

The above will supply your desired format in black digits, negative numbers in the same number format but bracketed and colored red; grey hyphen in place of zeroes and blue text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
$#.0,," M";-$#.0,," M";$#.0,," M";
```